# Left adjoint to the forgetful functor from Hilbert spaces to topological spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, adjoint-functors

I'm trying to generalize a method which can solve a problem involving discrete group to continuous group. And the method involve construct a "free vector space" from discrete space. So I'm trying to find a way to construct some kind of "free Hilbert space" from a topological space. But I have no idea how to achieve this goal. Then I find that one can get a free group or free vector space by considering the left adjoint of forgetful functor, so I wonder if one can go this way to get "free Hilbert space". But I don't know how to construct this adjoint.

Let $\mathbf{Hil}$ be the category of Hilbert spaces, $\mathbf{Top}$ be the category of topological spacces, and consider the forgetful functor $ F : \mathbf{Hil} \to \mathbf{Top}.$ Does this functor $F$ have a left adjoint? If it does, what is this left adjoint?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): include some work in your post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clear about what my question is, I add the problem I had in the question.

Comment: @Chen Ignore the bot.

Comment: Your question was already clear enough. What was/is lacking is some thoughts and/or attempts.

Answer (score 9):

The left adjoint does not exist. Otherwise, also the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Hilb} \to \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ to the category of sets had a left adjoint (since [left adjoints "compose"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682136/composition-of-adjoint-functors)), but it doesn't:

[Is there a concept of a "free Hilbert space on a set"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813427/is-there-a-concept-of-a-free-hilbert-space-on-a-set)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I have to try other way to generalize the method.